# Trouble integrating libraries into HTML - Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to open the example chart from the `Chart.js` documentation in a Google Chrome extension.

However, I run into an issue on `line 2` where i get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined` error.

What adjustments do I need to make in order to fix this issue?

*Keep in mind that I have the javascript in an external file rather than localized in the `html` file as the documentation does. This has to be done because of chrome's security engine*

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body class="background-opening-page">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="line-of-text">a line of text</div>
            <script src="popup.js"></script>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
            <script src="draw-chart.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How is the javaScript code executed? `Chart.js` might not have been `initialized`

Comment: > How is the javaScript code executed? What do you *exactly* mean by that lol. I'm pretty new to javascript so i dont exactly know how to answer your question.

Comment: Is the js file `draw-chart.js`? Also I don't see where `Chart.js` is imported in this HTML file

Comment: Yep the js file is `draw-chart.js`. I should have been more concise with that mb. I also didnt import the module :I whoops. Do i just add `import('./node_modules/chart.js');` at the top of the javascript file?

Comment: Add this in your `<head></head>` tag - `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>`

Comment: I added that to the head tag but chrome's security policy wont let it through. I need to gain access to the module another way

Comment: Read the last paragraph of this [link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html) and download the `css` files from [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.9.3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221296/discussion-between-gunt-r-and-codemax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the `chart.js` files locally and add to the `<head></head>` tags like this -

```
<script src="path/to/chartjs/dist/Chart.js"></script>
```

Also, please move this `<script src="draw-chart.js"></script>` into the `<head></head>` tag after the `Chart.js` tag. You should not be adding `<script>` tags inside the `<body>` tag.